# integer promotion of bit-wise operation and endiannes issue

Tags: c, types, linux-kernel, endianness, integer-promotion

Consider the following snippet from code running in the Linux kernel:

```
    char *d;
    u32 mask, step, val;
    ...
    /* d is initialized with valid pointer pointing at buffer,
and mask, step and val are initialized to some sane values as well. */
    ...
    val = (*d & mask) >> step;
```

As you see only `d` is of `char *` type, the rest are unsigned integers. I know that C performs type conversions automatically when
values of differing types participate in expressions, in this case
bit-wise operation. So, I'm assuming it is guaranteed that `*d` will be promoted to `uint32_t` as well?

If this assumption is correct, my 2nd question would be about the *byte-order* of 4 bytes located at memory pointed by `d`. I think it has to be whatever byte-order the host implements, or if it's networking, then strictly big-endian.

Comment: This code snippet does not depend on endianness. It does depend on the *signedness* of `char`.

Comment: It is *converted* to uint32_t, yes. But how it is done is depending on whether it is signed or not.

Comment: `*d` is one byte, so no order matters.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It is internal to the compiler and used only for the calculation.

Comment: The single byte `*d` will be either sign-extended to 32 bits or zero-extended to 32 bits, depending on whether `char` is signed or not.

Comment: @IanAbbott So to avoid this signedness of char, I could write it as val = ((u32)(unsigned char)*d & mask) >> step; ?

Comment: Yes, but does it need to be `char *` to start with, rather than, say, a `u8 *`?

Comment: @IanAbbott the code snippet I showed in the post was written before me, and I'm wondering why it cant' be `unsigned char *d`, probably for efficiency reasons?

Comment: It woudn't be for efficiency reasons. It might be because it was passed as a `char *` from further up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `d` has type `char *` it reads a *single* byte at the address pointed to by `d`.  So the expression `*d` has type `char` which has the value of the byte pointed to by `d`.  Endianness doesn't matter here because only a single byte is read from `d`.

In the larger expression `*d & mask`, the value `*d` which has type `char` is *converted* to `uint32_t` for use in the expression.

Comment: thanks for comments. So after promotion to `int` and later on conversion ti `u32` (or `uint32_t`), the endiannes matters. Will it be the host endiannes? I updated the question, because I see the same in linux kernel, where is processes network socket buffers, so whatever has arrived from the network is stored in `skb`, and it is in `network` byte-order.

Comment: How did you conclude the endianess matter? In your posted code the value of `val` *does not depend* on the endianness of the machine

Comment: @Mark The endiness matters only after you've read each byte individually and have to interpret them.  `*d` only pulls one byte from the buffer, not 4.

Comment: [This is](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) (and [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3))how it is converted. Note the lack of any endianess reference.

Comment: @Mark `*d` is one byte, holding a value from -128 to 127.  When it is converted, it will still have a value in that range.  Converting `*d` to a larger type doesn't automatically pull the next 3 bytes after the one `d` points to.

Comment: @dbush, so it means that `printf("%08x", *d)` will produce the same result on any byte-order machines?

Comment: @Mark Correct.  It's only a single byte, so endianness does not come into play.

Comment: CPU registers do not have endianness. Once a byte has been read from memory into a register, any binary bit-masking (and-ing) and shifting operate on the arithmetic binary value of the register as a whole.

Comment: @DavidRTribble is it always guaranteed that operands (in this case bitwise operations) will be in CPU registers?

Comment: @Mark As far as the C language is concerned no, although in practice it will probably be the case.

Comment: @Mark, It's hard to conceive of an existing CPU architecture that does not load its registers with expression operands at some point. But my point is that integer operands do not have an endianness within evaluated expressions, just binary values of some bit width. In other words, `1 << 12` will be the same value regardless of CPU endianness. Endianness is simply not relevant to integer expression evaluation.